# ViewModel observe on extended Activity

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

For my application, I have base implementations of core classes that take care of much of the boilerplate code. Two such implementations are of `BaseActivity` and `BaseViewModel`. The `BaseViewModel` simply has getters and setters for [`SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) which are accessed by the `BaseActivity`:

**`BaseActivity`:**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/* Some random variables */

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BaseViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BaseViewModel.class);

    // Observe loading state
    viewModel.getLoadingEvents().observe(this, showLoading -> {
        if (showLoading != null) {
            showLoadingState(showLoading);
        }
    });

    // Observer error events
    viewModel.getErrorEvents().observe(this, throwable -> {
        if (throwable != null) {
            Alerts.displayError(this, throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });
}

/* Some random methods */

}
```

Now I have other activities (such as `MainActivity`) which extend from `BaseActivity`. I'd have assumed that since `MainActivity` extends `BaseActivity` the aforementioned lifecycle observer would automatically apply for `MainActivity` as well. However, that is **not** the case. They only work if I move the observers to `MainActivity` from `BaseActivity`

Basically, what I am asking is **how can I keep the observer logic in the BaseActivity and have it properly apply for all extended classes?**

Comment: I'm looking for the answer too, please let me know when you find it.